Run jobs in `each` expression run in sequence in Azure Devops
In Azure DevOps one can run jobs in sequence as described here. However, in my case I am creating a list of jobs based on some input parameter and I want to know how I can run them in sequence:
jobs:
  - ${{ each weight in split(parameters.cutoverWeights, ',') }}:
    - template: internal/Cutover.job.yml
      parameters:
        name: CutTraffic_${{ weight }}
        dependsOn: ??

For example, if cutoverWeights is 1,5,100, this will create 3 jobs: CutTraffic_1, CutTraffic_5 and CutTraffic_100. How can I ensure CutTraffic_5 runs after CutTraffic_1 and CutTraffic_100 runs after CutTraffic_5?

The only solution I have found is as follows:
jobs:
  - ${{ each weight in split(parameters.cutoverWeights, ',') }}:
    - template: internal/Cutover.job.yml
      parameters:
        name: CutTraffic_${{ weight }}
        dependsOn:
          - ${{ each otherWeight in split(parameters.cutoverWeights, ',') }}:
            - ${{ if lt(otherWeight, weight) }}:
              - CutTraffic_${{ otherWeight }}

Though this only works for ordinal ordering if there is some simple relation in the input list that is supported by the limited YAML pipeline expressions available. For example, 1,2,3,4 or region1,region2,region3.
If you want integer ordering instead of ordinal string ordering (for example in case of input 1,5,10,24,100) you can use condition:
- ${{ if or(lt(length(otherWeight),length(weight)), and(eq(length(otherWeight),length(weight)), lt(otherWeight,weight))) }}:

This seems like a hacky solution. So if a better solution is provided in the future I will accept that one.


How can I ensure CutTraffic_5 runs after CutTraffic_1 and CutTraffic_100 runs after CutTraffic_5?

In each expression, we are not able to automatically assign the value of the current element to the name field and then assign the next element to the DependsOn field.  In one loop, the value of the weight parameter remains unchanged.
To meet your requirement, we need to use object type parameters to explicitly define the job name and the name of the dependsOn job.
Here is an example:
Main YAML:
parameters:
- name: cutoverWeights
  type: object
  default: 
    - name: CutTraffic_1
      dependsOn: 
    - name: CutTraffic_5
      dependsOn: CutTraffic_1
    - name: CutTraffic_100
      dependsOn: CutTraffic_5


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


jobs:
  - ${{ each weight in parameters.cutoverWeights }}:
    - template: internal/Cutover.job.yml
      parameters:
        name: ${{ weight.name }}
        dependsOn: ${{ weight.dependsOn }}

Template YAML:
parameters:
- name: name
  type: string
- name: dependsOn
  type: string


jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
  steps:
    - script: echo "test"

Result:


While this works it is not acceptable to me because it exposes the implementation details of this YAML to its users. The user needs to provide an additional dependency parameter AND know that the dependency should be set in a way to run the jobs sequentially.

@pooya13 Thanks for your feedback. I can understand your concern. But it is not currently supported to select elements in the each loop to set the corresponding fields. The value of the weight parameter is unchanged during one loop. We need to explicitly define the dependsOn details to let the pipeline work.

Thank you for your response Kevin. See my answer. I do wish Azure YAML pipeline syntax was more complete, but for this specific scenario I believe my solution would be more user friendly.

@pooya13 Yes. I have checked your answer. It can be an option, but it has more limitation on the parameters value. There is no perfect way to meet the requirements. I also suggest that you can report the feature related to your requirement in this site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest It will attract the attention of azure devops developers.

By default jobs run in parallel but stages run sequentially.
If you cannot change your parameter to object as suggested in Kevin's answer try generating a stage for each job:
stages:
  - ${{ each weight in split(parameters.cutoverWeights, ',') }}:
    - stage: ${{ weight }}
      jobs:
        - template: internal/Cutover.job.yml
          parameters:
            name: CutTraffic_${{ weight }}


Be very careful if doing this. Personally I would not advise this. If these are truly jobs with dependencies baked in then realize that stages are viewed as re-runnable packages of jobs with all dependencies contained in the stage.
This means that I can run stage 2 independently of stage 1. Thus the option to "re run a stage" after completion. Not a job. Additionally this will quickly lead to larger then desired pipelines depending on your configuration. i.e if a Dev->QA->PROD in one pipeline now I have taken 3 stages and multiplied by x amount jobs.

@DreadedFrost there are advantages and disadvantages of each approach: a) running all jobs in the same stage or b) running jobs in separate stages. OP is asking about running jobs in sequence, without providing additional context. You shouldn't downvote my answer based on so many assumptions about the pipeline when (I repeat) there is no additional context.
